# Refresh token becomes invalid every time django server restarts

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am using simple jwt tokens for authentication purposes in my django rest + reactjs app. As usual I am using axios interceptors in my react frontend to check if the access token has expired, if yes, then it sends a request first to the token-refresh api to get the new pair of tokens.

What I have noticed now and which is giving me problems is that suppose I make some changes in a code in django and the server restarts after saving, the refresh token becomes invalid so next time if the interceptors make a request to the refresh api it throws the below error

```
{
  "detail": "Token is invalid or expired",
  "code": "token_not_valid"
}
```

Hence, I have to logout the user every time after every restart in the server.

Below are the simple jwt settings

```py
INSTALLED_APPS=[
    "rest_framework",
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
 
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )

}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=1),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=7),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': True,
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After going through the codes again and again, I realised that nothiing was wrong in the simple jwt settings, but the problem lay somewhere else actually. The problem was the **SECRET_KEY**

I was supposed to get the secret key value from the .env file for which I wrote the code

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("DJANGO_SECRET_KEY", get_random_secret_key())
```

The above code means if you find a value in **DJANGO_SECRET_KEY** placed in the .env file use that else use **get_random_secret_key()** to generate a random secret key. The error that I made was in the .env file, rather than declaring the variable name as `DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=ahhjkhjds` what I did was I declared the variable as `SECRET_KEY=ahhjkhjds`. So, what this was doing, since `os.envrion.get` was not getting a value for **DJANGO_SECRET_KEY** it was generating a new secret key every time the server reloaded with the help of **get_random_secret_key()**

This inturn was influening a setting in simple jwt settings, i.e.,

```
SIMPLE_JWT= {
   'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
}
```

So basically every time the server was reloading because the **SECRET_KEY** had a new value, the value of the **SIGNING_KEY** changed. Hence, the old refresh token became invalid, even when it did not expire, as its **SIGNING_KEY** value was not matching with current one.

Hence, I was getting the error `Token is invalid or expired` when I tried to get a new access token after it expired with the already generated refresh token.